# Tracking the state of checkboxes generated via a for loop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm generating a series of checkboxes from a MySQL query that returns the list of databases on the server and am having trouble figuring out how I can track the state of the checkboxes since they're not individually assigned variable names due to variations in the size of the list. Is this possible? Or do I need to take a different approach to the creation of the checkboxes themselves?

The checkboxes are generated to have a state of `False` by default, but if the user selects a checkbox I need to store that information (specifically the text) for future use. They are generated in the `createGridLayout` function.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

databases = []

# Randomly generated database names
for i in range(10):
    databases.append('db' + str(i))

db_count = len(databases)
row_num = 0

class App(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'MySQL Timing Discrepancies'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 100
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createGridLayout()

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Databases")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 0)

        # Generating checkboxes here
        for i in range(db_count):
            col_num = i % 3
            row_num = i if col_num == 0 else row_num
            cb = QCheckBox(databases[i])
            cb.setChecked(False)
            layout.addWidget(cb, row_num, col_num)

            # Does nothing because they are defaulted to False
            if cb.isChecked():
                print(cb.text())

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list to track the `QCheckBox` texts by adding or removing depending on whether it was checked or unchecked, respectively. And to get the text you can use the `sender()` method that returns the object that emits the signal, and in this case you must use the `stateChanged` signal from the `QCheckBox`:

```py
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QCheckBox,
    QDialog,
    QGridLayout,
    QGroupBox,
    QVBoxLayout,
)


databases = ["db{}".format(i) for i in range(10)]


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "MySQL Timing Discrepancies"
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 100
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self._databases_checked = []

        self.createGridLayout()

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)

        self.show()

    @property
    def databases_checked(self):
        return self._databases_checked

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Databases")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
        for i in range(3):
            layout.setColumnStretch(i, 0)

        row_num = 0
        # Generating checkboxes here
        for i, database in enumerate(databases):
            col_num = i % 3
            row_num = i if col_num == 0 else row_num
            cb = QCheckBox(database)
            cb.setChecked(False)
            cb.stateChanged.connect(self.on_stateChanged)
            layout.addWidget(cb, row_num, col_num)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_stateChanged(self, state):
        checkbox = self.sender()
        text = checkbox.text()
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self._databases_checked.append(text)
        else:
            self._databases_checked.remove(text)
        print(self.databases_checked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Another way is to store the checkboxes in a list and iterate over them to get the text of the QCheckBox that are checked:

```py
# ...

self.checkboxes = []

row_num = 0
# Generating checkboxes here
for i, database in enumerate(databases):
    col_num = i % 3
    row_num = i if col_num == 0 else row_num
    cb = QCheckBox(database)
    cb.setChecked(False)
    self.checkboxes.append(cb)
    layout.addWidget(cb, row_num, col_num)
```

```py
texts = [cb.text() for cb in self.checkboxes if cb.isChecked()]
print(texts)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Hadn't considered the use of `property`. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *

class Checkbar(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):

      Frame.__init__(self, parent)

      self.vars = []

      for pick in picks:

         var = IntVar()

         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)

         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)

         self.vars.append(var)

   def state(self):

      return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)

if __name__ == '__main__':

   root = Tk()

   lng = Checkbar(root, ['Python', 'Ruby', 'Perl', 'C++'])

   tgl = Checkbar(root, ['English','German'])

   lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=X)

   tgl.pack(side=LEFT)

   lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)


   def allstates(): 

      print(list(lng.state()), list(tgl.state()))

   Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)

   Button(root, text='Peek', command=allstates).pack(side=RIGHT)

   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is a tkinter code the solution for a pyqt5 code?